# Get error by using repository interface extending JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, interface, model, repository

I have this model:

```
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @Column(
            nullable = false,
            unique = true
    )
    private String email;
    @Column(
            nullable = false
    )
    private String password;
    @Column(
            updatable = false
    )
    private Date created_at;
    private Date updated_at;
    private Date deleted_at;
    @OneToOne
    private Usermeta usermeta;

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        created_at = new Date();
    }

    public User() {

    }
}
```

And this Repository Interface:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

If I want to build my application I get this error:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration$StringHttpMessageConverterConfiguration.stringHttpMessageConverter   at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]   at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:183) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:428) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]     at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:349) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]   at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:118) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:788) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]   at com.kito.KitoBackendApplication.main(KitoBackendApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid value type for attribute 'factoryBeanObjectType': java.lang.String    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getTypeForFactoryBeanFromAttributes(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:86) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:837) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:575) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:534) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:247) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:240) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:230) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:183) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:158) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]   ... 17 common frames omitted`

Nothing so far. I tried to create a repository class and implement the JpaRepository but this is not what i wanted.

Comment: That's a known "issue". One of your dependencies (or your code) set a string on a bean which is an error now.